# How to retrieve multiple Extended Properties use EWS and Java

Tags: c#, java, outlook, exchangewebservices

I have created two "User-Defined" fields in the contacts folder in Outlook 2010.  I'm using the Java port of the C# EWS API.  My goal is to read the value of the fields for each contact for a specific user.  The problem to this point has been retrieving more than one field.  In my code below you'll find that I define multiple (2) fields that are extended properties that I want to access.  However, in the output, I only retrieve, at most, 1 field.  For Example, a contact has both fields, it will only return the first one it finds.  If it only has 1 of the two fields, it will return which ever one is populated.  Any ideas?

```
private static void printContacts(ExchangeService service, int numOfContacts) throws Exception{        
    // Defined the properties you want to retreive
    ExtendedPropertyDefinition propertyOne = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings, "property1", MapiPropertyType.String);
    ExtendedPropertyDefinition propertyTwo= new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings, "property2", MapiPropertyType.String);

    // Push the customer properties into an arary
    ExtendedPropertyDefinition[] list = {propertyOne , propertyTwo}; 

    // Create a property set to hold the properties
    PropertySet propertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, list);

    // Get items from mail box        
    ItemView view = new ItemView(numOfContacts);               
    try {            
        FindItemsResults<Item> contactResults = service.findItems(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts, view);

        for(Item item : contactResults.getItems()){
            item.load();

            Contact contact = Contact.bind(service, item.getId(), propertySet);

            System.out.println("count: " + contact.getExtendedProperties().getCount());

            for(ExtendedProperty prop : contact.getExtendedProperties()){
                String propertyName = prop.getPropertyDefinition().getName().toString();
                String propertyValue = prop.getValue().toString();

                System.out.println(propertyName +" : "+ propertyValue);
            }

        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

When I print out the count of extended properties, its always one, even if both extended properties are set.  Any help would be appreciated.